# How do I copy data in a table with formulas into another sheet without removing the formulas in the original table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro that copies data from a range (R9:U14) and pastes the values into a table on another Tab (Record tab).

This works fine but the issue I have is that in my source range (R9:U14) are formulas. After the Macro runs it has removed any formulas that were in the source range and only left the values.

Please help.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    DoEvents

    Sheets("Pending Sales").Select
    Range("R9:U14").Select
    Range("U14").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Record").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheets("Pending Sales").Select
    Range("R9:U14").Select
    Range("U14").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Pending Sales").Select
    Range("R9:U14").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
       

        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        
End Sub
```

Comment: The last three lines of code before the save method paste your values over top of your original table. Otherwise, the answer from @FreeSoftwareServers is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the Macro Recorder which is a great place to start, but you always want to go in and edit the generated macro to be more generic. Googling key terms to like "copy range vba".

I'm not 100% what the problem is with your original code, but try this.

```
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Pending Sales").Range("R9:U14").Copy destination:=Worksheets("Record").Range("A2")
```

Or

```
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Pending Sales").Range("R9:U14").Copy
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Record").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```